# Creating ActiveX control(OCX) in VB .net 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, activex, ocx

I would like to create an activeX control(OCX) in VB .net 2010 is it possible?
I having a hard time determining how to make it because I only get a .dll file rather than a .ocx which can be seen in vb6. I hope you can answer my question.

Comment: An .ocx file is just a .dll file with a funny last name.  Like me.  .NET has *some* support for true ActiveX controls, the kind that have a visual appearance on a VB6 form.  You have to derive your class from the System.Windows.Forms.Control class.  Monkeying with [the registry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2fe50909-f7f8-4500-a99c-34de2ef567f6/activex-control-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) is required to make it show up in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to create an "ActiveX" control specifically or are you asking how to create controls that can be used by other CLR based applications?

To create an ActiveX control, see this link which walks you through the steps to do this: [Creating an MFC ActiveX Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc13as7d(v=vs.100).aspx)

To create standard controls, you use a dll (class library) and can add as many controls to it as you like. You don't need a dll for each control, although you can.