# Make VB.NET appear directly in Excel sheet instead of in userform?

Tags: vb.net, excel

I can add a date picker to a userform and then show that userform in Excel. But is there a way to make the date picker appear directly in the Excel sheet?

The main reason why I do not want to use a userform is because the userform title and borders have no purpose in my application. Ideally, I would also like the month control disappear when I select a different sheet and then reappear when I reselect the original sheet. Additionally I would like it to not have its own window, but rather be part of the Excel window.

[image]

Comment: DatePicker is a System.Windows.Form control , excel is other type of object ! You can export in excel just Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel controls .. digg in this way ..

Comment: Make your date picker an ActiveX control ([\[1\]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24089/Create-ActiveX-in-NET-Step-by-Step), [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25563436/creating-activex-controlocx-in-vb-net-2010#comment39942108_25563436)) and put it on the sheet as a usual control.